# ATX PC reboot, does power supply actually cut off power to components?

Tags: power-supply, atx

When I issue the reboot command in OS, does it actually affect power supply output (12V rail in particular)?

For instance, PC B uses PC A's power supply for hard drive (SATA power) and graphics card (6+2 PCIE power). When PC B reboots, does it affect PC A?

Comment: Why don't you try it see what happens? This is a question you can easily answer yourself.

Comment: A reboot should utilize the `reset` circuitry of the computer while the PSU maintains its output.  This can cause differences between a cold boot, i.e. power-on reset, versus a warm boot, i.e. a reset while powered up, on a poorly-designed computer and/or peripheral, or a poorly-written device driver.  FWIW there is no reset signal either going to or from the PSU at the ATX power connector.